# copy etherdelta code

Tags: solidity, dapps, exchanges, decentralized-exchange

For a test project, I need to write the etherdelta's contract. but "function EtherDelta (address admin_, address feeAccount_, address accountLevelsAddr_, uint feeMake_, uint feeTake_, uint feeRebate_) {
    admin = admin_;
    feeAccount = feeAccount_;
    accountLevelsAddr = accountLevelsAddr_;
    feeMake = feeMake_;
    feeTake = feeTake_;
    feeRebate = feeRebate_;
  }

function () {
    throw;
  } "I don't know how to fill this part. I'm getting an error because I can't fill this up, and I can't print the contract.

Comment: Post at least links to the code you are talking about please.

Comment: I have edited..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EtherDelta contract constructor takes the following arguments:
`function EtherDelta(address admin_, address feeAccount_, address accountLevelsAddr_, uint feeMake_, uint feeTake_, uint feeRebate_)`

Are you setting these to sensible values when deploying the contract through Remix?

They should be something like:

"0xadminadddress...", "0xfeeaccount...", "0x0", 0, 0, 0

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for your response. When I lift that part completely, I can write the contract. but I'm doing something wrong when filling up. can you show me how to fill the sample with?
section: function EtherDelta (address admin_, address feeAccount_, address accountLevelsAddr_, uint feeMake_, uint feeTake_, uint feeRebate_) {
    admin = admin_;
    feeAccount = feeAccount_;
    accountLevelsAddr = accountLevelsAddr_;
    feeMake = feeMake_;
    feeTake = feeTake_;
    feeRebate = feeRebate_;
  }

  function () {
    throw;
  }